# Android app sees Restlet web service form emulator, but does not from device. (I dont use localhost adress)

Tags: android, web-services, android-emulator, restlet

I am very great-full for all those times i managed to solve my problems using this site, and this is the first time i have to ask for help. I hope that it will be successful, and i give my gratitude to any one who may try to help.

So, i have **android app** that uses **Restlet** api to communicate with **restful web service**.
Those are the facts:

1. **App is working on emulator**.
2. I am using local lan address of server machine (**192.168.1.x**), and android device is in the same network.
3. I **can** access ws from browser on other machine connected trough wifi.
4. I **can** access ws from browser on phone, but can not from app itself.
5. **Firewall is disabled.**

Is there anything else i might need to configure in android app so it could work on real device? I am assuming that it can establish a connection, since i can access WS from browser on phone.
Could it have something to do with Restlet api?

Thanks in advance,

Nikola

Comment: How do you say that you cannot access it from your app? Don't you get an HTTP response at all? Does the request time-out?

Comment: Please post your LogCat stack trace.